# PostgreSQL: Casting two separate numeric values to a point

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, geospatial, spatial

I'm trying to change the application schema of a database in Postgres...so I need to copy data from one table to another. In the original table, co-ordinates are specified as numeric values in two separate columns, one for the x value and one for the y value. In the new table, the co-ordinates need to be stored as one value of the point data type. How would I cast the two separate numeric values into one that is a point?

Comment: What is the data type of the point representation?

Comment: When I created the new table, I just chose the data type to be of type "point" that was listed as an option at the drop down menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
INSERT INTO New_Table (my_id, my_point)
SELECT
    my_id,
    POINT(x, y)
FROM
    Old_Table
```

I don't have PostgreSQL on my machine here, so I can't test it, but I think that's the syntax.

X and Y are supposed to be double precision numerics. I don't know what your X and Y data types are and I don't know what implicit conversions PostgreSQL will do for you, so you may need to do a convert there as well.

Comment: I do have postres on my machine here, and can confirm that this is the correct syntax.  thanks!